# Is /proc/mounts file depracated?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, unmount

I have been reading at several places that we should no longer refer to /proc/mounts and instead it is better to rely on /proc/self/mountinfo file. For example, see this question:

[/proc/self/mountinfo per-mount-options vs per-super-options](https://serverfault.com/questions/581178/proc-self-mountinfo-per-mount-options-vs-per-super-options/581180#581180?newreg=24fda00edc5a42dc85817702b98abdad)

However, I can't find any official documentation stating the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is `/proc/mounts` file depracated? ... I can't find any official documentation ...*

According [proc(5) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

> *`/proc/mounts`*
>
> *Before Linux 2.4.19, this file was a list of all the filesystems currently mounted on the system.  With the introduction of per-process mount namespaces in Linux 2.4.19 ... this file became a link to `/proc/self/mounts`, which lists the mounts of the process's own mount namespace. ...*

See also

```shell
ll /proc/mounts
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11 Jul 18 14:45 /proc/mounts -> self/mounts
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. While it states that it is a link to /proc/self/mounts, it nowhere says that this is not a reliable method. So wondering if it is ok to use /proc/mounts?

Comment: `/proc/mounts` is just a symlink now. Since it is pointing to properly defined target there is no need to use the "old" one other than for backward compatibility. And it might disappear in the future. Therefore, just use the final target from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you @U880D
That answers my question :)
So basically I can just use /proc/self/mounts or /proc/self/mountinfo instead of /proc/mounts.